# R: efficient dataframe split-apply(concatenate)

Tags: r, dplyr, concatenation

I am hoping to get some expert advice on a efficient way to remove rows of a dataframe in one column (columnA) where there is a duplicated value and at the same time create a new variable that concatenates entries of another column (columnB) in cases where columnA had duplicates.  Below I provide a toy dataframe:

```
my_df <- data.frame('DateTime' = c('2017/05/05 08:30:00', '2017/05/05 08:30:00', 
                               '2017/05/05 08:30:00', '2017/12/08 08:30:00',
                              '2018/01/15 18:50:00', '2017/12/20 21:46:00',
                              '2017/11/12 18:50:00', '2017/11/03 08:30:00',
                              '2017/11/03 08:30:00', '2017/12/03 08:30:00'),
                     'Event' = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A'),
                     'Var1' = rnorm(10),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

In this dataframe DateTime column is a character column and 2017/05/05 08:30:00 appears 3 times while 2017/11/03 08:30:00 appears twice.  My goal is to collapse rows where there are duplicates of `DateTime` and to have a new column that concatenates the `Event` entries.  So the new column, lets say `AllEvents`, should have entry `A-B-C` for 2017/05/05 08:30:00 row.  For row 2017/11/03 08:30:00 in the `DateTime` column `AllEvents` should have a value of `A-B`.  Finally, for all other rows, `AllEvents` should match `Event` column.

My attempt seems very clunky.

I first extract unique values of DateTime where there is more than one entr:

```
require(dplyr)
duped_datetime <- unique(my_df[duplicated(my_df$DateTime), 'DateTime'])
```

I then subset my_df to extract entries where there are duplicates

```
subset_df <- my_df[my_df$DateTime %in% duped_datetime,]
```

Next I create a function that concatenates a vector:

```
my_concat <- function(x){
concat_str <- subset_df %>% filter(DateTime == x) %>% 
                            select(Event) %>% 
                            unlist() %>% 
                            paste(collapse="+") 
return(concat_str)
}
```

Next I loop through the duplicated dates and apply the `my_concat` function:

```
named_vc <- sapply(duped_datetime, FUN = my_concat)
```

The results are combined into a new dataframe

```
new_df <- data.frame('DateTime' = duped_datetime,
                     'AllEvents' = unname(named_vc), 
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The results are merged and the final_df is cleaned up to keep the rows and columns I need.

```
final_df <- left_join(my_df, new_df, by = 'DateTime')  %>% 
            mutate(AllEvents = ifelse(is.na(AllEvents), Event, AllEvents)) 
final_df <- final_df[!duplicated(final_df$DateTime),]
final_df['Event'] <- NULL
```

I get the result that I need but as you can see the code is hideous.   The whole thing can be done in 4 lines in Python with groupby, apply, and lambda functions but it is not immediately obvious to me how to get the same task done cleanly in R.

```
    DateTime            Var1      AllEvents
2017/05/05 08:30:00   -0.8350209    A+B+C
2017/12/08 08:30:00    1.1534819    A
2018/01/15 18:50:00   -0.3501990    A
2017/12/20 21:46:00   -0.6664841    B
2017/11/12 18:50:00    1.7142981    C
2017/11/03 08:30:00   -2.0133559    A+B
2017/12/03 08:30:00   -0.6150040    A
```

Thanks to anyone who has the patience of reading this.

Comment: So do you just end up keeping the first `Var1` entry for each `DateTime` essentially? If so, you can do it in a couple of lines using `summarise` `paste` and `first`.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I should have included that in the question.  Marius and Renu gave two excellent examples.  Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done straightforwardly in `dplyr`, `group_by` works fine with the `DateTime` values:

```
my_df %>%
    group_by(DateTime) %>%
    summarise(Var1 = first(Var1),
              Event = paste0(Event, collapse = "+"))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  DateTime              Var1 Event
  <chr>                <dbl> <chr>
1 2017/05/05 08:30:00  0.159 A+B+C
2 2017/11/03 08:30:00 -0.610 A+B  
3 2017/11/12 18:50:00  0.465 C    
4 2017/12/03 08:30:00 -1.89  A    
5 2017/12/08 08:30:00  0.793 A    
6 2017/12/20 21:46:00  0.755 B    
7 2018/01/15 18:50:00  0.511 A
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of variety, here's the same thing in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my_df)

my_df[, .(Var1  = first(Var1)
        , Event = paste0(Event, collapse = "+"))
      , by = DateTime]
```

Gives

```
              DateTime       Var1 Event
1: 2017/05/05 08:30:00  0.2366874 A+B+C
2: 2017/12/08 08:30:00  0.3699069     A
3: 2018/01/15 18:50:00 -0.2420663     A
4: 2017/12/20 21:46:00 -1.4720633     B
5: 2017/11/12 18:50:00 -0.5961595     C
6: 2017/11/03 08:30:00 -1.1467001   A+B
7: 2017/12/03 08:30:00 -0.6135086     A
```

Note that the order of `my_df` is preserved.

Comment: R is a fantastic language.  Thank you Renu.  This may not be appropriate way to ask but can you recommend a go-to resource on data.table package?  Have you come across a book that is good on the subject?

Comment: The authors of the package have a course on datacamp: https://www.datacamp.com/courses/data-table-data-manipulation-r-tutorial. In addition, `?data.table` contains a surprising amount of information. As a third option, this R tutorial uses `data.table` http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/index.html.